# $input-height-inner-quarter undefined variable

Tags: sass, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to use custom theme in `nuxt.js` bootstrap `vue` but I have an issue on compile.

```
$input-height-inner-quarter undefined variable

 background-position: right $input-height-inner-quarter center;
                                ^
      Undefined variable: "$input-height-inner-quarter".
      in /node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/components/form-input/_form-input.scss (line 10, column 34)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the SCSS (not pre-compiled CSS).

Make sure you `@import` all the SCSS files into a single SCSS file that is then `import`'ed into your project.

Individual separate imports into your project will not share SCSS variables.

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/theming

Answer (score 0):

Between [Bootstrap 2.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.2.1/scss/_variables.scss#L492) and [Bootstrap 3.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/ac6eefd227374df0f4d7494e1119c66a443e502c/scss/_variables.scss#L498) variable names have changed, if you have bootstrap as a dependency in your package.json, it might be outdated!

Answer (score 0):

import into your styles.scss bootstrap styles first then bootstrap-input-spinner styles as shown in example: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tkrotoff/bootstrap-input-spinner/tree/codesandbox.io?file=/example/index.scss:0-36)

```scss
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '~@tkrotoff/bootstrap-input-spinner/src/bootstrap-input-spinner';
```